# How to get facebook result from javascript sdk to java

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using plain javascript to fetch feeds from the facebook by graph apis using fb javascript sdk.

However, my ultimate need is to parse the results and store it to my db via a java program.

So, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [restfb](http://restfb.com/) framework for acessing facebook graph api via Java

Comment: well is there facebook supported official api's for doing the stuff directly in java like fb provided javascript sdk ?

Comment: No, they dony have any java api at the time being

Answer (score 0):

Make the request from the Java environment, this would be much safer since you don't have to post the result from your javascript to the server hence avoiding that somebody malicious tampers with your javascript result.

Comment: oh how to do that? are there any java based apis available to get fb data ?